# How to use ClientScript.getpostbackclienthyperlink inside INamingContainer

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback, web-controls, inamingcontainer

I have a custom WebControl class which inherits from WebControl and INamingContainer. Inside this class is a gridview which I want to have clickable rows.

I have the gridviews `AutoGenerateSelectButton` set to `True` for the time being, but eventually I want to replace this with a row onclick event which posts back to the server.

In the gridviews `RowCreated` event I have the following code to add my desired onclick event to each row:

```
e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(this.gvUserList, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
```

Unfortunately, this doesnt work and generates a slightly different output to the select button due to my class inheriting from INamingContainer.

The generated output from the select button (which works) is:

```
onclick="__doPostBack('UserData$gvUserList','Select$2');"
```

Whereas the code generated from the ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink method is this:

```
onclick="__doPostBack('gvUserList','Select$2');"
```

Notice that the javascript for the select button prefixes the gridviews name with 'UserData$' (The ID given to my control from the page itself) because of the `INamingContainer` interface, while the postback client hyperlink does not.

How can I achieve the same generated output as the select button does with the GetPostBackClientHyperlink method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I have not been able to come up with an elegant solution to this, I have fixed it using the following code:

```
e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = "__doPostBack('" + this.UniqueID + "$" + gvUserList.ID + "', 'Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex + "')";
```

This is the best I could come up with. I still welcome other answers!